# Pyinstaller exe on linux with dask cluster causes multiprocessing bomb

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, python-multiprocessing, dask

I am creating a python executable in linux using pyinstller. The script uses Dask local cluster with `processes=True` argument. The script works fine while executing using python command in terminal. But it results in a multiprocessing bomb when run using the executable.

PS: I was able to resolve this in windows using `freeze_support()` in Windows, but couldn't find a way to do this in Linux.

Note: I'm using Python3.5.5 and pyinstaller3.6

Answer (score 0):

In Python you need to start additional processes in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block

```py
# myscript.py

import dask.distributed

... custom code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = dask.distributed.Client()  # spawns processes

    main()
```